# Introduce maths-functions specifications with ACSL/Frama-C

Tags: static-analysis, frama-c

Is it possible to implement specifications in ACSL for functions usually called at compiling with -lm, as sqrt ? I am using it for Frama-C's plug-in WP.

Here is a small example to illustrate what I would want to do.

```
/*@ requires sqrt_spec: \forall float x; 
             \model(sqrt(x)) * \model(sqrt(x)) == \model(x);  
    ensures [...] */  

void f (...) {
double y = sqrt x;
[...]
}
```

Obviously, if I do this WP cries because sqrt doesn't exist when I use it in annotations.

> [kernel] user error: unbound function sqrt in annotation

So I would like to define an abstract sqrt, but none of my tests worked :

```
#define sqrt(x) (...)
```

For this one I don't see what I could put in (...) as I want a abstract definition instead of re-implementing the whole float sqrt.

```
/*@  axiomatic SqrtSpec {
logic real sqrt (real x);
} */
```

And this one doesn't solve my problem :

> Neither code nor specification for function sqrt, generating default assigns from the prototype.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Frama-C has a built-in logic function `\sqrt` that operates over `real` number (note that built-in functions and predicates usually are prefixed with a backslash `\` to avoid any collision with existing C identifiers). That said, it is not that difficult to provide an axiomatic definition for `sqrt`:

```
axiomatic Sqrt {
  logic real sqrt(real);
  axiom real_def: \forall real x; x >= 0 ==> x == sqrt(x) * sqrt(x);
}
```

Note in addition that Gappa (http://gappa.gforge.inria.fr/) is about the only automated prover that knows about floating-points (as opposed to real numbers), but even if you have installed it, discharging proof obligations dealing with floating point computations can be very hard.

**Update**

If you want to axiomatize `double sqrt(double)` (and/or `float sqrt(float)`), the idea would be to characterize the error relative to the result of `\sqrt` operating on reals, i.e. something akin to

```
axiomatic Sqrt {
  logic float sqrt(float sqrt);
  axiom sqrt_def: \forall float x; \is_finite(x) && x>= 0.0 ==> sqrt(x) ==  (float)\sqrt(x);
}
```

Of course, this characterization might be a bit restrictive. You might want something like `\abs(sqrt(x) - \sqrt(x)) <= err_bound * \sqrt(x)`, but I have to admit that I'm not fluent enough in floating-point computations to give the appropriate value of `err_bound` from the top of my head.

**Update 2**

Assuming that you have a **logic** `sqrt` that has the properties you want, saying that the **C** `sqrt` has the same behavior is simply a matter of giving a contract to it:

```
/*@ requires \is_finite(x); //unless you want to play with NaN or infinities 
    assigns \nothing;
    ensures \result == sqrt(x);
 */
extern float sqrt(float x);
```

Specifications of a function are merged during the link phase, so that it does not matter whether this contract is written in `math.h` (NB: in the standard header `sqrt` takes (and returns) a `double`, it is `sqrtf` that operates on `float`) or in your own file.

Comment: I am sorry, I had probably been a bit unclear.   

I am looking for a specification concerning the **C function** _sqrt_, operating on **floats**. That is why I used _\model()_ in my example.  

My specification as for aim to specify that we assume that the C _sqrt_ function as some properties, like correctness (the _requires_ in my post) or boundaries from correctness.  

And I am actually implementing floats knowledge on WP...

Comment: OK, I did update my answer to introduce `logic float sqrt(float)`

Comment: IEEE 754 specifies `sqrt` as one of the operations that must be correctly rounded. In other words, `sqrt(x) ==  (float)\sqrt(x)` is a pretty good axiomatization for most usecases.

Comment: It is interesting, thank you, but I already knew that and it is not what is bothering me. I know that my English doesn’t help, sorry. **I don't want an axiomatic sqrt**. My problem is to ensure Frama-C that the sqrt (the C function) that I am using below has actually good properties, as a precondition. Doing what you suggest me doesn’t change anything to the lack of informations concerning the C function sqrt (introduced by -lm) that owns WP. I will still have the same warning : `[kernel] warning: Neither code nor specification for function sqrt, generating default assigns from the prototype`.

Comment: So I how to say Frama-C/WP : "Hey buddy, please assume that [the C-function] sqrt(x) == (float)\sqrt(x), and generate me preconditions with it". Do you guys know how to do this ?

Comment: @PascalCuoq True, as long as you accept that `sqrt` is in fact dependent on the program state (more precisely the rounding mode at the point of evaluation), which might appear a bit surprising (and not well-supported by current implementation). I didn't really want to mention such detail in my answer, thus stayed a bit vague.